# Posting twice intermittently .. using IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have come across this issue where on  occasions the post is happening twice using IE.

Here is what I have in my document ready.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myForm").submit(function () {
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
        Validatit();
    });
```

The validation that is called from within that.

```
 function Validatit() {
    var form = $("#myForm")

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
}
```

Last but not least the button.

```
<button id="submit" onclick="submitIt();">Submit items</button>
```

The submit submitIt just calls an ajax.

Originally, I had type="submit" on the button which I removed and then added e.preventDefault on my document ready.  That does not seem to work.

Do you see anything that maybe causing posting it twice. Again on occasions.

On the back end I have MVC plain old style with entity framework.

Comment: Aren't you getting `e is undefined` or something like that, given that your submit handler doesn't have `e` as parameter?

Comment: @ChrisG to check I tried this: `alert(e.defaultPrevented)` it states undefined. I tried also to add that as a param and it still says undefined.

Comment: @ChrisG on post, I do not get anything .. moved it inside form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an HTML5 button element. This button has a default behavior of submit, as stated in the W3 specification as seen here: [W3C HTML5 Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

So you need to specify its type explicitly with type="button"

```
<button type="button" id="submit" onclick="submitIt();">Submit items</button>
```

then you don't even need the e.preventDefault. (where the code was faulty to begin with, you need to pass the e as a parameter to the anonymous function callback)

```
$("#myForm").submit(function (e) {
```

Comment: I can try this, but I have posted before successfully.. so if it had to do with type.. it should not have worked even once.. Don't you think so? why would it work 99% of the time and then that 1% post twice. I do see signalR reference twice.. wonder if that may cause this.